# Filtering on multiple wildcard filenames when copying data in Data Factory

Tags: azure, copy, azure-data-factory

I am doing a simple Copy Data Data Factory pipeline.

I am accessing a folder & want to retrieve all files matching particular patterns.

I have been able to use the "Wildcard file name" only to match one of these.

Is there a way to input multiple wildcard file names?

I have tried;

(pattern1*.csv|pattern2*_pat.csv)

which copies nothing to the destination.

Any help much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have 1 pattern, however you should be able to use * and ? to match both: "Allowed wildcards are: * (matches zero or more characters) and ? (matches zero or single character)", from the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage#copy-activity-properties

If not, you can always have multiple copy activities, each with a different pattern.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thanks Martin! Yeah i figured multiple copies would be an option but managed to get a for loop with the copy activity within & learnt how to use the variables! Bit of guess work this Data factory atm :)